# What is the portable way to get the default route source address?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route

I need to get the IP address used as the source for packets **sent via the `default` route**. (EDIT) Please note that I am referring to the `default` route, the one marked as `default` in `ip r` (see at the end for the actual route the packets will take under my VPN setup).

My first idea was to use `ip r` and deduce this from there:

```
# ip r
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun0
default via 10.237.76.1 dev enxb827eb4297a4 src 10.237.77.206 metric 202
10.0.2.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.100
10.81.102.133 via 10.237.76.1 dev enxb827eb4297a4
10.237.76.0/22 dev enxb827eb4297a4 proto kernel scope link src 10.237.77.206 metric 202
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun0
```

It looked good, an `ip r | grep default | cut -d" " -f7` gave me the expected `10.237.77.206`.

Then, on another system (both are debian derivatives) I got

```
# ip r
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun0
default via 10.237.76.1 dev eth0  metric 202
10.0.2.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.5
10.81.102.133 via 10.237.76.1 dev eth0
10.237.76.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.237.76.56  metric 202
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun0
```

Here the solution is not as simple: I need to extract default route IP (`10.237.76.1`), match it with the appropriate route (`10.237.76.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.237.76.56  metric 202`) which will hopefully include the `src`.

Ultimately cutting from the output of `ip` will not hold water in the lng term (changes in output, variations in the output between distros or versions, ...)

**Is there a more portable way to get that IP?**

By "portable" I mean:

- ideally "works on any Linux"
- less ideally but still good "works on Debian and its derivatives"

Please note that the device is in an exclusive VPN so I cannot directly analyze the actual route the packet will take when the VPN is up (that is, most of the time): the `default` route is masked by two other routes, which effectively cover the whole IP range. Please correct me if I am mistaken here.

Comment: Generally, if there is a more specific route that matches, then that route is chosen over the default route (and also over any other route with a shorter matching prefix). If you have routes that cover the whole IP range, the default route is never used.

Comment: You’ll need to apply the ``ip route get`` solution with ``10.81.102.133`` to get the information you want. If this IP is static, that’s fine, if it’s not… hmm :(

Comment: @JohanMyréen: yes I know, this is what I am referring to the `default` route, as printed by `ip r` (I stressed this part in my question to clarify)

Comment: @WoJ **My** point is that your default route has no effect if you have more specific routes that cover the whole IPv4 Internet. You can just as well delete the default route. It is not used.

Comment: @JohanMyréen: Yes I know that it has no effect when the VPN is up, but no, I cannot remove it because this is the route which will be used should the VPN fall down for some reason. This is the way OpenVPN enforces its own "effectively default" route without disturbing the original `default` one (to fallback on it when it is down)

Comment: @WoJ OK. As you have noted yourself, all the answers mentioning `ip route get` are wrong for your setup. The source address selection is not trivial, the `src` parameter on the route is just a hint, and is optional. The communicating program may bind an address, which is used instead. See http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-saddr-selection.html

Answer (score 7):

For showing your default route source address:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8  | awk ' /^[0-9]/ { print $7 }'
```

- The `{ print $7 }` is selecting the 7th field of the `ip...` output;
- The `^[0-9]` is selecting lines starting with a number as `ip` generates two lines, to chose the correct line.

Note: I prefer this first solution, however showing other alternatives for the sake of showing alternatives.

Or:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 |  cut -f7 -d" " | grep '^[0-9]'
```

Again:

- the `cut` selects the 7th field;

Or:

```
 ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep ^[0-9] |  cut -f7 -d" "
```

Or:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | fgrep src |  cut -f7 -d" "
```

Or also:

```
 ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk ' /src/ { print $7 }'
```

To clarify a bit, here is the output of `ip`:

```
$  ip route get 8.8.8.8 
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.249 
   cache
```

There are several methods of getting the default route in Linux, either via `ip`, `procfs` or from `netstat`. `netstat` is becoming deprecated, and IMO, `ip` is a better choice that is present in any recent Linux distribution.

Comment: this doesn’t work. It outputs quite a few source addresses on my machine and it is trivial to make it produce wrong output on the first line.

Comment: @JonasWielicki What is the output of your `ip route show default `?

Comment: ```default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.190.239.10 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-5969808f1117 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.25.0.0/24 dev br-e46206f425fe proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown ```

Comment: (And adding a route ``ip route add 1.0.0.0/8 dev eth0 proto kernel src something`` would make the first line of the ``| awk`` thing output ``something``.)

Comment: Also, if I added the route to the default router manually for some reason, it would not have ``proto kernel``, at which point your ``awk`` would not give any output.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I agree with you, though i find it odd `ip route show default` being so verbose on your machine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JonasWielicki user4556274 is right into the `ip route get`, replaced mine with it. What would be the result now in your system? curious.

Comment: The ip route get solution works, even though I’m not sure why you’d copy another users solution instead of just keeping your answer deleted… Regarding the verbose output, that’s because of docker.

Comment: Keep it deleted for a while, but then thought adapting it for the route command of the other answer and leaving it here for the benefit of OP and others.

Comment: This solution will give me the IP for the **current** default route (which is the one going through VPN, see the last part of my question), not the one described as `default` in `ip r`

Answer (score 7):

You could choose an arbitrary address which you believe will always be accessed via the default route, for example google DNS, and then print the source address for *that* route:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{ for (nn=1;nn<=NF;nn++) if ($nn~"src") print $(nn+1) }'
```

Comment: And this methods is easily extended with adding `mark ...` , `from ... iif ...`

Comment: Whilst it seems a bit convoluted, this answer is more smart into being independent of position, and should be the accepted answer. +1

Comment: This solution will give me the IP for the **current** default route (which is the one going through VPN, see the last part of my question), not the one described as `default` in `ip r`

Comment: @WoJ, how about with `ip route get 8.8.8.8 oif eth0` ?  (Yes, I realize this just pushes the problem to 'how do I specify the desired interface?' for now)

Answer (score 1):

Building on actual intent (finding the original output IP) and answers made, here's a (quite long) one-liner that should do the trick:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 oif $(ip route | sed -n '/^default/s/^.* dev \([^ ][^ ]*\) *.*$/\1/p')  | sed -n 's/^.* src \([^ ][^ ]*\) *.*$/\1/p'
```

1st step inside `$()`: get the default route, retrieve only its interface after the keyword *dev* (because depending on conditions that might depend or not on the distribution, the route will or won't show the source ip at this step)

2nd step: get a route to a "well known" public IP address that should have no special route setting tampering with it, but asking to use the previous retrieved interface, so actually asking the kernel to use the actual original default route buried under `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1` to do the calc. Retrieve the IP after the keyword *src*

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario (setting up a docker container to get the host's ip correctly) i decided this way:

```
ip route|awk '/src/ { print $7 }'
```